# Why are my React images not loading in the web browser?

Tags: reactjs, browser, runtime-error

[image: This is the output is reflecting]

My React app’s images are not rendering in the browser. The images folder is in src rather than public. How can I load the images in my React project? Here is my current image pathing:

```
<a href="/" className="logo">
            <img src="../src/comp/images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
          </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that `../src/comp/images/logo.png` is not a path that's available or makes sense to the webserver. If you're using vite, this is the purpose of the public folder. Assets that are placed into the public folder are made statically available to the webserver.

If you can't use the public folder, try this:

```
import Logo from '../src/comp/images/logo.png';

<a href="/" className="logo">
            <img src={Logo} alt="logo" />
          </a>
```